# Ctrl, Alt and Super keys are all mapped as left Shift key on AZiO keyboard

Tags: keyboard, remapping

I bought a keyboard yesterday, AZiO L40 (Model: ABG600F).

Everything works fine in Windows, but when I boot into Ubuntu, both of my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys, <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys, and <kbd>Super</kbd> keys are recognized as left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key. Even my right <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is recognized as left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

I have tried `xev`, and confirmed that Ubuntu indeed recognized them all as left <kbd>Shift</kbd>. I tried those remapping strategy using `xmodmap`, but since my OS thinks they are all left <kbd>Shift</kbd> I can't remap them.

My OS is Ubuntu 13.10, and here is the result of `lspci`:

```
Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller 
PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port 
Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 
USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 
Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller 
PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 
PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 
USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller 
ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller 
SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tahiti PRO [Radeon HD 7950]
Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tahiti XT HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7970 Series]
Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57788 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
```

And here is the output of `lsusb`:

```
Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Card Reader/Writer
Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Microdia 
Logitech, Inc. G400 Optical Mouse
Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Strangely, my keyboard is connected via USB, but it is not shown here.

Is there anything I can do? If nothing works, I'll have to return the keyboard, since I can't live without <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

Thank you for all your help in advance.